Failed to load the default quality profiles: No organization with key
I was trying to set up SonarQube scan for my GitHub repo, but getting error Failed to load the default quality profiles: No organization with key
Here is how the action looks like
on:
    # Trigger analysis when pushing in master or pull requests, and when creating
    # a pull request.
    push:
      branches:
        - main
    pull_request:
        types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
name: Sonar Check
jobs:
    sonarcloud:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v4
          with:
            # Disabling shallow clone is recommended for improving relevancy of reporting
            fetch-depth: 0
        - name: SonarCloud Scan
          uses: sonarsource/sonarcloud-github-action@master
          with:
              args: >
                 -Dsonar.organization=xxx
                 -Dsonar.projectKey=xxx
                 -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io
          env:
            GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
            SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}

Sonar project properties
sonar.organization=xxx
sonar.projectKey=xxx

# relative paths to source directories. More details and properties are described
# in https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/
sonar.sources=.
sonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io

What is wrong here?

Not sure if it's related. What's the name of the properties file and where is it located in your repo?

@Azeem, - sonar.project.properties

According to docs, it should be sonar-project.properties.

You're welcome! Did it fix your issue?

@Azeem, yes, thanks, you may add it as an answer.
